# ImageView прорисовывается не полностью

Tags: android, view, imageview

Я динамически отрисовываю на экране линию - создаю ImageView, задаю ему размеры и фон. Иногда (закономерности выявить не удалось) вьюшка отрисовывается не полностью, хотя LayoutParams сообщает, что длина нужная

На что стоит обратить внимание?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: здесь код вставляют как текст, картинка ничего не проясняет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что вьюшка отрисовывалась вправо, а затем поворачивалась
Видимо, если вью выходит за экран, Android не отрисовывает её полностью, поэтому при повороте показывалась только та часть, что отрисовалась